# Is there another step involved in creating a JS bundle for Vue SSR?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, server-side-rendering, vue-cli-3

I am building a Vue SSR application to render a simple vue component server side. After following on with the official vuejs website guid, I ended up creating two entry files `server-entry.js` and `client-entry.js`, the client entry works fine and renders the component without any issues. However when I build the server entry, it builds without issues, giving me a `js/<bundle>.js` and `css/<bundle>.css`. But when I run the `server.js` file with:

```
node src/server.js
```

the terminal shows that it's running and listening on the port 8080. But when I visit localhost:8080. I have the following error:

```
TypeError: createApp is not a function
    at server.get (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/src/server.js:9:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/home/osama/projects/quran-embed/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I don't understand why it tells me that **createApp** is not a function, though it is.

NOTE: I am using Vue CLI 3.

Here are the related files:

app.js

```
// https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html#code-structure-with-webpack
// app.js the universal entry

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import {createRouter} from './router'
import {createStore} from './store'

import './assets/scss/main.scss'

Vue.config.productionTip = false


// export a factory function for creating fresh app, router and store
// instances
export function createApp() {

    // create router instance
    const router = createRouter()

    // create store instance
    const store = createStore()

    // inject router into root Vue instance
    const app = new Vue({
        router,
        store,
        render: h => h(App)
    })

    // return both the app and the router
    return {app, router}
}
```

entry-server.js

```
// entry-server.js
import {createApp} from './app.js'

export default context => {
    // since there could potentially be asynchronous route hooks or components,
    // we will be returning a Promise so that the server can wait until
    // everything is ready before rendering.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const {app, router} = createApp()

        // set server-side router's location
        router.push(context.url)

        // wait until router has resolved possible async components and hooks
        router.onReady(() => {
            const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents()
            // no matched routes, reject with 404
            if (!matchedComponents.length) {
                return reject({code: 404})
            }

            // the Promise should resolve to the app instance so it can be rendered
            resolve(app)
        }, reject)
    })
}
```

server.js

```
// server.js
const createApp = require('../dist/js/quran-embed.js');
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer();
const server = require('express')();


server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const context = {url: req.url};
    createApp(context).then(app => {
        renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 404) {
                    res.status(404).end('Page not found')
                } else {
                    res.status(500).end('Internal Server Error')
                }
            } else {
                res.end(`
                  <!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html lang="en">
                    <head><title>Hello</title></head>
                    <body>${html}</body>
                  </html>
                `)
            }
        })
    })
});

server.listen(8080);
```

vue.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = {
    css: {
        extract: {
            filename: 'css/quran-embed.css',
        },
        // extract: false,
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            filename: 'js/quran-embed.js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
        },
        target: 'node',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
                maxChunks: 1
            }),

        ]
    },
    chainWebpack:
        config => {
            config.optimization.delete('splitChunks')
        },
    filenameHashing: false
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "quran-embed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve-client": "vue-cli-service serve src/entry-client.js",
    "build-client": "vue-cli-service build src/entry-client.js",
    "build-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build src/entry-server.js",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "at-ui": "^1.3.3",
    "at-ui-style": "^1.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap-v4-rtl": "^4.4.1-1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "document-register-element": "^1.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsdom": "^16.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-custom-element": "^3.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.5.16",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

If you look at the `package.json` file, you can find the script `build-server` that I use to build the bundle for SSR.

I am not sure if my issue with the createApp not being identified as a function is related to my setup or it's just a ES6/Javascript thing.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you mix `export` with `require()` which is [considered a bad practice](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2934).

You can try to move `createApp` to `client-entry.js` and use [bundleRenderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/bundle-renderer.html#enter-bundlerenderer) instead of classic renderer. However it needs some more setup, and you can find a really good example of how to do it [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/build/setup-dev-server.js)